# PHP - Download finishes before the end

Tags: php, file, download

I made a download routine on PHP and had no problems with it until I put some large files in there. I can download 400~500mb without a problem, but larger files than that are finishing before completing. For example, a 700mb file is finished when it gets around 500mb. I've tried different files and extensions and got the same result.

Here's my code:

```
$file = utf8_decode($_GET['d']);


header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file);
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Pragma: public');

$file = "../uploads/$curso/$file";
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

if(ob_get_level()){
    ob_end_clean();
}

readfile($file);
```

I tried putting set_time_limit(0) and increasing the max_execution_time but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should really sanitize the filename before using it in your code... if someone does something like: `?d=../../../somefile` or similar, he can fetch all kinds of stuff...

Comment: look in your web server log and see why it is not finishing?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there aren't any gzip/output compression enabled. That could mess up your downloads.

I've heard before that `readfile()` still have some issues while reading large files. Try this instead:

```
...all your headers...

$data = @fopen($file,"rb");
while(!feof($data))
{
    print(@fread($data, 1024*8));
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

This reads and outputs the file in small chunks.